# restrict access to certain files, folders in python tornado web server

Tags: python, tornado

I'm launching a tornado web server in python3, here's some simplified startup code:

```
import tornado.ioloop, tornado.web
root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
startPage = 'index.html' 

class allStops(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('yo man')

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/API/allStops", allStops),
        (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": root, "default_filename": startPage})
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(5005)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

The webserver works fine. I have various files and folders around index.html. So when we open `localhost:5005` in browser we see the contents of the index.html (a static website), and with the links in it can access all other things. I can also just access them directly by putting in URL.

That's where my problem lies. If this program is in `launch.py` then I'm able to see the whole program from the browser through `localhost:5050/launch.py`. I want to **disallow** that. I also want to prevent browser access to contents of a particular subfolder. But at the same time, I don't want to restrict access to all the other files and folders: the default allow-all state is good. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `StaticFileHandler` and then validate the filenames in [`validate_absolute_path`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler.validate_absolute_path) method. Raise 404 or 403 errors for files you don't want to serve.

```
from tornado import web
from tornado.web import HTTPError

class MyStaticFileHandler(web.StaticFileHandler):
    def validate_absolute_path(self, root, absolute_path):
        if absolute_path.endswith('.py'):
            # raise 403 Forbidden error for all files ending with .py
            raise HTTPError(403)

        return super().validate_absolute_path(root, absolute_path)
```

And then use this class in your url handler.

---

#### Customising error response:

If you set `debug=False`, then Tornado will automatically show an appropriate message related to the status code instead of the exception.

If you want to send a custom error template, you can do this:

```
...

def validate_absolute_path(self, root, absolute_path):
    if absolute_path.endswith('.py'):
        self.set_status(404)
        # send a custom 404 response from an html file
        with open("path/to/404.html", "r") as f:
            self.write(f.read())

        return None

    return super().validate_absolute_path(root, absolute_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great! How do we customize the error message the user gets?

Comment: thanks.. I'm writing a line with `self.write()` and then ending with `return None`. Does the job on browser, but in console I get an error message: `ERROR:tornado.general:Could not open static file None` . Also, not sure where the `debug=False` goes.

Comment: But the `ERROR` message in terminal only appears once, not with every ping, and i don't think it's messing up with anything so we're good :)

Comment: @NikhilVJ Did you also remove the `return super()...` line from the method? `return None` should live inside `if` block. For other cases you have to return the path of the file (by calling `super`). I've updatde the code to reflect this.

Comment: Hi @xyres, yes, the super() is there only. I just updated tornado at my end from 5.1 to 6.1 and now it raises an `AssertionError` if we `return None` - they've specifically coded to tackle us doing that. I guess I have to make a custom error page after all - not a problem - better for easy future changes in fact.

Comment: Confirming.. I put this in the if loop and works fine now; no more errors: `return os.path.join(root,'lib','errorpage.txt')`